# How to fetch spring.datasource.username correctly from application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I've been working on a spring-boot project in which configuration needs to be done using `application.yml`

The `application.yml` file located under directory `src/main/resources`.

This is the content of the file:

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: XX
  datasource:
    username: admin
    password: 1234
    driverClassName: XXXX
    url: XXXX
```

Within configuration class I have variables for every field.

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class GlobalConfig {

    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String driverClassName;
    private String url;


    // getters&setters
```

And this is the runner file:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.yml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private GlobalConfig globalConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setGlobalConfig(GlobalConfig globalConfig) {
        this.globalConfig = globalConfig;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(globalConfig);
    }
```

Although every other variable is correct in the application `username` field has some content related to the user of the **operation system**.

Expected toString -> `GlobalConfig{name='XX', username='admin', password='1234', driverClassName='XXX', url='XXX'}`

Actualt toString -> `GlobalConfig{name='XX', username='user', password='1234', driverClassName='XXX', url='XXX'}`

PS: Letter `X` **doesn't** mean its null. They are populated already!

I've already checked some similar questions but there was no answer for this case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you populate `GlobalConfig` from the `application.yml` file?

Comment: I've updated the question and added the runner file. I've been using `CommandLineRunner`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't print Object without populating data from yaml file.

you can make use of "Setter" or "construction" Injection. ( you need to populate all data to POJO right?)

For Ex (Setter Injection)-

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Component
public class GlobalConfig {

 private String name;

    @Autowired
    public void setName(@Value("${user.name}") String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
//getter
}
```

application.properties:-

user.name= johnson

Then autowire GlobalConfig n print object System.out.println(globalConfig);

Comment: The POJO is getting populated automatically. The question doesn't ask for your answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by automatically? i can not see how the date you are populating here. you are just calling null object using CommandLineRunner.

Comment: No, they are not null. They are populated already. The problem is that one of the fields is populated incorrect. There's a conflict, that's the main problem actually. Please read the question again.